# How to send a message to a specific user in pyTelegramBotapi?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id == chatId)
def store_text(message):
user_response = message.text

bot.reply_to(message, "What do you want to improve?")

# Send an improvement wish to yourself
bot.send_message(my_user_id, f"New improvement: {user_response}")
```

I am using an inline button>.

I want the bot to send me a message whenever there's a new improvement